# How do I insert MergeField into specific table cell with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I work in Word 2007. I am trying to insert a mergefield into specific cell (i.e first cell of the second row), but without success. With simple inserting mergefield I have no problem:

```
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
    "MERGEFIELD  $!test ", PreserveFormatting:=True
```

But when I try to insert mergefield into cell it throws an error:

> Run-time error '4605'. The command is not available.

This is the code what I tried:

```
    collectTable.Cell(1, 1).Select
    Selection.Fields.Add Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="MERGEFIELD $!testField", PreserveFormatting:=True
```

and also I tried this:

```
collectTable.Cell(1, 1).Select
Selection.Fields.Add collectTable.Cell(1, 1).Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="MERGEFIELD $!testField", PreserveFormatting:=True
```

But the result is same. How can I insert a mergefield in table cell with VBA script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion when you select cell inside table the selection includes end-cell mark which could not be replaced with the field. You need to select cell range which doesn't include that final mark.

I suggest the following improvement of your code:

```
Dim collectTable As Table
Set collectTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

'selecting cell range without cell-end mark
ActiveDocument.Range(collectTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Start, _
                    collectTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.End - 1).Select

Selection.Fields.Add Selection.Range, _
            Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
            Text:="MERGEFIELD $!testField", _
            PreserveFormatting:=True
```

Comment: For greater flexibility, assign the result of the 
ActiveDocument.Range(collectTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Start, _
                    collectTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.End - 1).Select
line to a Range variable.